# Analog Reading 16f877a in CCS C

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am writing code for a line follower,I have to read 7 analog values from different channels and make the robot act accordingly,I read different kinds of tutorials on this issue and tried to apply the things I read there ,however was not successful,here is my code:

```
    //all these # below set up the PIC
#include <16F877A.h>
#device adc=10
#FUSES NOWDT      //No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES HS         //Highspeed Osc > 4mhz
#FUSES PUT        //Power Up Timer
#FUSES NOPROTECT  //Code not protected from reading
#FUSES NODEBUG    //No Debug mode for ICD
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT //No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP      //No low voltage prgming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O
#FUSES NOCPD      //No EE protection
#use delay(clock=20000000) //crystal oscillator at 20000000 hertz

void fwrd(int16,int16);
void left(int16,int16,int16);
void right(int16,int16,int16);

unsigned long threshold = /*0b0011101100;*/ 0b1011001100;
unsigned long a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,S_dec,S_dec_last;
unsigned short d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6;
unsigned short big=40;
unsigned short middle=30;
unsigned short small=20;
unsigned short current_duty=59;
unsigned short current_duty1=41,gtime=80;


//main program starts here
void main() {
   setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_DIV_32); //configure analog to digiral converter
   setup_adc_ports(ALL_ANALOG);   //set pins AN0-AN7 to analog 

   while(true){      
      set_adc_channel(0);//set the pic to read from AN0
      delay_us(20);//delay 20 microseconds to allow PIC to switch to analog channel 0
      a0=read_adc(); //read input from pin AN0: 0<=photo<=255

      set_adc_channel(1);//set the pic to read from AN1
      delay_us(20);
      a1=read_adc();

      set_adc_channel(2);  //set the pic to read from AN2
      delay_us(20);
      a2 = read_adc();
      set_adc_channel(0);//set the pic to read from AN0
      delay_us(20);//delay 20 microseconds to allow PIC to switch to analog channel 0
      a0=read_adc(); //read input from pin AN0: 0<=photo<=255

      set_adc_channel(1);//set the pic to read from AN1
      delay_us(20);
      a1=read_adc();

      set_adc_channel(2);  //set the pic to read from AN2
      delay_us(20);
      a2 = read_adc();

      set_adc_channel(3);//set the pic to read from AN4
      delay_us(20);//delay 20 microseconds to allow PIC to switch to analog channel 4
      a3=read_adc(); 

      set_adc_channel(4);//set the pic to read from AN1
      delay_us(20);
      a4=read_adc();

      set_adc_channel(5);  //set the pic to read from AN5
      delay_us(20);
      a5 = read_adc();

      set_adc_channel(6);//set the pic to read from AN6
      delay_us(20);//delay 20 microseconds to allow PIC to switch to analog channel 4
      a6=read_adc(); 


if (a0<threshold)
d0=0;
else d0=1;


if (a1<threshold)
d1=0;
else d1=1;

if (a2<threshold)
d2=0 ;
else d2=1;

if (a3<threshold)
d3=0 ;
else d3=1;

if (a4<threshold)
d4=0 ;
else d4=1;

if (a5<threshold)
d5=0 ;
else d5=1;

if (a6<threshold)
d6=0 ;
else d6=1;

S_dec=d6*64+d5*32+d4*16+d3*8+d2*4+d1*2+d0;
if (S_dec!=0b0000000)
{S_dec_last=S_dec;
switch (S_dec)
       { 
          case 0b1101000:
          case 0b1111000:
          case 0b1111100:
          case 0b1111110:
          case 0b1101100:
          case 0b1001100:
          case 0b1011000:
                left(4.4*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case 0b1000000:
          case 0b1100000:
          case 0b1110000:
                left(3.6*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case   0b0100000:
          case   0b0110000:
          case   0b0111000:
                 left(3*gtime,current_duty-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case   0b0010000:
          case   0b0011000:

                 left(1.2*gtime,current_duty-middle,current_duty+small);
          break;

          case   0b0001000:
          case   0b0011100:
                 fwrd(gtime,current_duty+middle);
          break;

          case   0b0001100:
          case   0b0000100:
                right(1.2*gtime,current_duty-middle,current_duty+small);
          break;

          case   0b0000110:
          case   0b0000010:
          case   0b0001110:
                 right(3*gtime,current_duty-middle,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case   0b0000111:
          case   0b0000011:
          case   0b0000001:
                 right(3.6*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;
          case   0b0001011:
          case   0b0001111:
          case   0b0011111:
          case   0b0111111:
          case   0b0011011:
          case   0b0011001:
          case   0b0001101:
              right(4.4*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

         }

}   else
    S_dec=S_dec_last;
switch (S_dec)
       { 
          case 0b1101000:
          case 0b1111000:
          case 0b1111100:
          case 0b1111110:
          case 0b1101100:
          case 0b1001100:
          case 0b1011000:
                left(4.4*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case 0b1000000:
          case 0b1100000:
          case 0b1110000:
                left(3.6*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case   0b0100000:
          case   0b0110000:
          case   0b0111000:
                 left(3*gtime,current_duty-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case   0b0010000:
          case   0b0011000:

                 left(1.2*gtime,current_duty-middle,current_duty+small);
          break;

          case   0b0001000:
          case   0b0011100:
                 fwrd(gtime,current_duty+middle);
          break;

          case   0b0001100:
          case   0b0000100:
                right(1.2*gtime,current_duty-middle,current_duty+small);
          break;

          case   0b0000110:
          case   0b0000010:
          case   0b0001110:
                 right(3*gtime,current_duty-middle,current_duty+big);
          break;

          case   0b0000111:
          case   0b0000011:
          case   0b0000001:
                 right(3.6*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;
          case   0b0001011:
          case   0b0001111:
          case   0b0011111:
          case   0b0111111:
          case   0b0011011:
          case   0b0011001:
          case   0b0001101:
              right(4.4*gtime,current_duty1-big,current_duty+big);
          break;

         }

   }
}
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Your code does not show the important functions, setup_adc. Please post those.